# Checking greater than for date not working

Tags: oracle, date, conditional-statements

I am trying to fetch data based on greater than condition for date field. The stored format of date "08-MAY-13". I have added the condition

```
      SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE JOINING DATE > TO_DATE('14-NOV-13','dd-mm-yy').
```

But in the results i see '08-MAY-13' date also appearing. Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't `N0V` be `NOV`?

Comment: Your TO_DATE function is likely malfunctioning. Or perhaps you are passing in wrong parameters (e.g. "NOV" instead of "11" for the month).

Comment: or change the format mask to 'dd-mon-yy'

Comment: I cannot change the date format underlying in the table. I have looker access that's it.

Comment: i tried to use dd-mon-yy. But still 08-MAY-13 appears

Comment: That TO_DATE looks like Oracle but isn't going to generate anything other than "ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found" since your date string doesn't match the specified format string.  So show us what you are really trying to execute?

Comment: So ifi do not specify the format '14-NOV-13','dd-mm-yy' it gives date is not correct format. It is in oracle. With this format Oracle does not throw any error but fetches result by not correctly executing greater than condition

Comment: Actually the dates are coming another eMatrix DB and getting added into oracle datasource. I cannot change the date

Comment: 'NOV' is a month abbreviation and you are trying to convert it by 'MM' which requires a number between 01 and 12.  Show us the actual query and the DDL for emp table and some sample data.  Then it might be possible for us to lend assistance.

Comment: Also, you mention "stored format of date".  Please, please understand that if the column in the oracle table (JOINING DATE) is of data type DATE (which it _should_ be) then it's 'format' is oracle internal binary format for dates, not the character string that you show.  That's the whole purpose of TO_DATE - to convert a character string to a DATE.  Also, I see "WHERE JOINING DATE > ", with a space between 'JOINING' and 'DATE'.  That is itself invalid syntax.  You need to show us what you are _really_ doing.  Also, please, please, please use 4-digit years.

Comment: You absolutely need to post the table definition, the actual full query, and the data and what version. Basically, [mre]. However, like others I was sure your date format was incorrect, but I have always insisted you must **test**, so I did. And shockingly the your TO_DATE as is ***actually [worked correctly](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=42cdddc76023e7b2d8dfb153bbaa927b)***.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should give format to date column, like:

```
SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE JOINING TO_DATE(DATE,'dd-mm-yy') > TO_DATE('14-11-13','dd-mm-yy');
```

I hope to be helpful.